# script to monitor wifi connection dropouts

Tags: windows, wifi-configuration

I suffered WiFi dropouts (WiFi swapped to "Limited") using an ISP provided router for weeks. I have since upgraded my networking equipment and I would like to monitor my WiFi connection for a few days to see if it's properly fixed. I haven't noticed any dropouts since the upgrade but I want to be 100% sure. (Oddly, only my Windows laptop suffered the drop outs - the iPads and iPhones in my home were fine.)

Does anybody know how I could monitor the state of my WiFi connection? I would preferably like to check it every minute or so and just leave the script running for a few days. I'm not very good with Windows so happy to be pointed away from a script if you can recommend anything.

**Note:** It's Windows 8.1 x64; I know it's slightly vague but I don't know where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't your router itself log disconnection events? Anyway you can try the following script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objLog = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\NetLog.txt", False)
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\wmi")
Set colMonitoredEvents = objWMIService.ExecNotificationQuery("Select * from MSNdis_StatusMediaDisconnect")
Do While True
    Set strLatestEvent = colMonitoredEvents.NextEvent
    objLog.Write "[" & Date & " " & Time & "] A network connection has been lost: " & strLatestEvent.InstanceName & vbCrLf
Loop
```

Save it as something like **NetCheck.vbs** and run, then turn off your router and see if the disconnection is logged properly or not. To end logging kill Wscript.exe via Task Manager.

Comment: I unfortunately can't find anything relevant on the router. It only happens to the Windows laptop and I have no idea why. I use the ISP router as a modem now and simply connect it via Ethernet to a much better router. Yet, just now, my laptop dropped to "Limited" and yet the broadband was reporting fine (on the ISP router - iOS devices still worked). Do you know how I can diagnose what's actually happening when it drops to Limited? Thanks for the full script!

Comment: Not sure, perhaps there's some interference or bandwidth congestion. A separate question devoted to diagnosing the issue might throw up some answers from others.